# Does jest automatically restore mocked modules between test modules?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, jestjs

Does jest automatically restore mocked modules between test files?  For example, if I call `jest.mock('some_module')` in one file, do I need to ensure I call `jest.unmock('some_module')` after all the tests are run in that file?

It's not clear to me whether that happens in the documentation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You don't have to reset the mocks, as the test are run in parallel, every test file run in its own sandboxed thread. Even mocking JavaScript globals like `Date` or `Math.random` only affects the actual test file.

The only problem we had so far was mocking `process.env.NODE_ENV` which affected other test that run at the same time. But reseting this after the test run solved the problem.

Comment: Great.  Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: What about --runInBand mode?